# In SSRS, how can input multiple data into text box?

Tags: reporting-services

I'm trying to construct a report in SSRS and I would like to know if instead of using a multiple selection drop down box to search for a particular set of serial numbers, I can give users the ability to manually enter multiple serial numbers of their choice into a text box.

The list of serial numbers in the particular data set is quite large, so with a drop down user would be scrolling through thousands of serial numbers, as opposed to just typing in serial numbers of interest.

Answer (score 2):

You can do this using a parameter

1. Add Parameter
2. In the general properties amend the data type and check Allow Multiple values
3. Click OK
4. Right click on your data set query
5. Left click DataSet Properties
6. Left click Parameters
7. Add the parameter you created in 1 above - preceded by @
8. Click on fx
9. in the expression dialog key =SPLIT(JOIN(Parameters!.Value,","),",")
10. Click OK
11. Click OK
12. Amend your dataset query to include  where something in(@)
13. Save the amended query
14. Preview the report
15. A parameter box will appear
16. Click on the drop down
17. Enter a comma separated list of serial numbers
18. Click on view report

Using adventureworks added a parameter @soid
The split statement is

```
=SPLIT(JOIN(Parameters!SOID.Value,","),",")
```

The dataset query is

```
SELECT SalesOrderID, RevisionNumber, OrderDate, DueDate, ShipDate, Status,  n                                OnlineOrderFlag, SalesOrderNumber, PurchaseOrderNumber, AccountNumber,      CustomerID, SalesPersonID, TerritoryID, BillToAddressID,                             ShipToAddressID, ShipMethodID, CreditCardID, CreditCardApprovalCode,  CurrencyRateID, SubTotal, TaxAmt, Freight, TotalDue, Comment, rowguid,  ModifiedDate
FROM Sales.SalesOrderHeader WHERE   SalesOrderID in (@SOID)
```

Comment: Thanks for chiming in. I used your example above, but I'm still having issues. Once the split join is introduced and I run the report the serial number dropdown box is grayed out. It's render useless. The parameter is set to visible so I'm a bit unsure of what's going on.

Comment: Here is a sample of my where clause with my parameters:

where (Descr IS NOT NULL) AND (A1.ClassId > 0) AND (A1.Code IN (@code)) AND (A1.ClassId IN (@plan))  AND  
(A1.servicedate BETWEEN CAST(@startdate AS datetime) AND CAST(@enddate AS datetime)) AND (A1.PostedDAT BETWEEN @datepostedbegin AND 
@datepostedend)AND (A1.SerialNumber IN (@SerialNumber))

Comment: Odd - so points 14 - 18 don't work for you? I can't reproduce this problem just yet even after adding 2 date parameters, although I do notice that the parameter appears greyed out in preview (it's fine in report manager).One thing to check, SSRS is (unusually for MS) very fussy about parameter case sensitivity.

Comment: From a quick google there was a "feature" in SSRS which caused this behaviour. The "resolution" suggest by MS was to try changing the parameter order. As a matter of interest which versions of SSDT and sql server are you using?

Comment: Sorry for the delayed response. I'm using sql server 2008. I'm not sure how to tell the version of SSDT.  Wouldn't it be the same version of sql server 2008?